# how to set a UI that easily span to any ios device?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

This might be generic question, wanted to know if theres way to set an unique UI or the view for an ios device using swift that can be easily span to any ios device without being broken. I have read through couple of articles and saw few videos but no one gives a proper answer of what are the basics of setting the UI element that makes it easier to be spanned across devices

Comment: Do you mean [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You could use auto-layout or you can do the plumbing yourself by implementing *layoutSubviews* for each of your custom views (you can think of auto-layout as a layer above layoutSubviews). If you'd implement *layoutSubviews* directly you might also want to override methods like *sizeThatFits*.